How many times does a callback run for a single send operation in Kafka?
I have the following callback:
ListenableFuture = kafkaTemplate.send(record);
future.addCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable e) {
        logger.warn(e, record.value());
    }
    @Override
    public void onSuccess() {
        // do nothing
    }
}
});

I noticed that TimeoutExceptions are repeatedly logged every minute for as long as my Kafka writes are failing. But I can't seem to determine a clear pattern for how often they are repeated and this doesn't seem consistent across messages.
As a side note on the 20000ms, that's the value I've set for delivery.timeout.ms. I don't know where 20001ms is from.
Does anyone know how many times a callback gets executed for a single send operation in Kafka? I thought it would be once, but the tests I've run prove otherwise.
> grep -a "Expiring " app.log | sort
 org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 1 record(s) for test-topic-0:20000 ms has passed since batch creation
 org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 1 record(s) for test-topic-0:20001 ms has passed since batch creation
 org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 1 record(s) for test-topic-1:20000 ms has passed since batch creation
 org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 1 record(s) for test-topic-1:20000 ms has passed since batch creation
 org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 1 record(s) for test-topic-1:20000 ms has passed since batch creation
 org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 1 record(s) for test-topic-1:20000 ms has passed since batch creation
 org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 1 record(s) for test-topic-1:20001 ms has passed since batch creation
 org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 1 record(s) for test-topic-1:20001 ms has passed since batch creation
 org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 1 record(s) for test-topic-1:20001 ms has passed since batch creation
 org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 1 record(s) for test-topic-1:20001 ms has passed since batch creation
 org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 1 record(s) for test-topic-1:20001 ms has passed since batch creation
 org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 1 record(s) for test-topic-1:20001 ms has passed since batch creation
 org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 1 record(s) for test-topic-2:20000 ms has passed since batch creation
 org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 1 record(s) for test-topic-2:20000 ms has passed since batch creation
 org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 1 record(s) for test-topic-2:20001 ms has passed since batch creation
 org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 1 record(s) for test-topic-3:20000 ms has passed since batch creation
 org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 1 record(s) for test-topic-4:20000 ms has passed since batch creation
 org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 1 record(s) for test-topic-6:20000 ms has passed since batch creation
 org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 1 record(s) for test-topic-6:20000 ms has passed since batch creation
 org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 2 record(s) for test-topic-1:20001 ms has passed since batch creation
 org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 2 record(s) for test-topic-1:20001 ms has passed since batch creation
 org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 2 record(s) for test-topic-4:20000 ms has passed since batch creation
 org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 2 record(s) for test-topic-4:20000 ms has passed since batch creation
 org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 2 record(s) for test-topic-4:20000 ms has passed since batch creation
 org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 2 record(s) for test-topic-4:20000 ms has passed since batch creation
 org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 2 record(s) for test-topic-5:20000 ms has passed since batch creation
 org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 2 record(s) for test-topic-5:20000 ms has passed since batch creation
 org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 2 record(s) for test-topic-6:20001 ms has passed since batch creation
 org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Expiring 2 record(s) for test-topic-6:20001 ms has passed since batch creation

Edit: I've added logging of the producer record in the future callback and can confirm that only for one message, the hash appears every minute (= same message entering the onFailure method?), and more times than the number of retries I've configured. And for some other producer records I tried to send, only one log in their callback onFailure method is logged.
Edit 2: Updated question from "Does anyone know how to make sure each timeout exception only logs once?" to "How many times does a callback run for a single send operation in Kafka"

I think there's a logback config to limit repetition based on the classname
